# Specific Java Regex For Set Notation

Tags: java, regex, set, notation

I'm trying to write a regex expression that will check that a string is in the formation of a Set of integers

```
ex: {1, 23, -501, 52, 2387329, 0}
```

So far I've got:

```
Pattern p = [({(([0-9]+,)*[0-9]+)})]
```

But it doesn't seem to be working... Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't handle `-` sign?? Can you show some examples of strings that work and don't work?

Comment: One useful technique as you develop complex regular expressions is to build them up from named Strings.  `String lbrace = "[{]";` and `String sInteger = "[+-]?\\d+";`. Then build up your pattern from these. Look at the mail pattern in the second edition of Mastering Regular Expressions.

Comment: I'm very new to regex and am not really sure what I'm doing here. Some examples that work would be:
{1, 2, 3}
{}
{3}
and those that don't work are:
{1 2 3}
{a, b, c}

Comment: Do you _want_ `{1 2 3}` and `{a, b, c}` to work?

Comment: No. They should be numbers separated by commas. I can always take the spaces out by formatting the string, so even the spaces aren't necessary

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern.compile("\\{\\s*(?:\\d+(?:\\s*,\\s*\\d+\\s*)*)?\\}")
```

matches curly brackets surrounding zero or more comma-separated non-negative decimal integers.

`\\s` matches any space character.  The `(?:...)` are just for grouping, and the stuff between the curly brackets is effectively (decimal digits followed by (any number of commas then decimal digits)) optionally.

I don't know what notation you're using for

> ```
> [({(([0-9]+,)*[0-9]+)})]
> ```

but it will definitely not match the empty set and won't match anything with spaces after a comma.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
"\\{((-?\\d+), ?)*-?\\d+}"
```

Comment: For some reason {1 2 3} is working with it. Is there any reason why that would be happening?

Comment: I tested "{1 2 3}".matches("\\{((-?\\d+), )*-?\\d+}"); it returns false

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
        String data = "{1, 23, -501, 52, 2387329, 0}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(\\s?-?\\d+?\\,?\\s?)+?\\}");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        // Indicates match is found. Do further processing
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```